# forEach method on Firebase invokes callback with child snapshot with undefined key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It's been a few months I started learning JavaScript, since I am an IOS developer, I prefer Firebase as my backend for my websites too.

So on today's practice, I used to read Firebase data and alert it to myself, I used this code,

> Notice: those code's are only examples and used during my work, and it officially comes from Firebase's documentation.

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();

query.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      // childData will be the actual contents of the child
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        alert(key); // also tried the (key.value); as well
  });
```

and here is my Firebase structure:
[image: Screenshot]

and the output:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's funny but firebase doesn't update their docs as often as their API changes, even worse if you're using Angular 4+. Try rewriting your code like this below. you need to return a boolean value after iterating a snapshot with forEach:

```
    var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
    query.once("value", (function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
          var key = childSnapshot.key;
          // childData will be the actual contents of the child
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();

          alert(key); // also tried the (key.value); as well
          return true;

      })
)
```